# looking for solution about Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"

Tags: android, sqlite

```
2020-06-19 13:11:53.531 25613-25613/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-06-19 13:11:54.270 25613-25667/com.example.testfosavedata E/OpenGLRenderer: Device claims wide gamut support, cannot find matching config, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2020-06-19 13:11:54.327 25613-25667/com.example.testfosavedata E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2020-06-19 13:17:26.886 25613-25613/com.example.testfosavedata E/SQLiteLog: (1) table notestable has no column named title
2020-06-19 13:17:26.891 25613-25613/com.example.testfosavedata E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting title=rdgy content= hggh
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table notestable has no column named title (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO notestable(title,content) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: Please give more information about what you want to achieve. Could share a piece of code to us ?

Comment: Looks like a premission thing, check if you have premission for your app to acess internet and local storage or what ever, also in your sql The column called title is not there so it gives an eerror there aswell but that could be premission related or related to something wrong with database